# Transforming List into a Json C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to convert a List into a Json to send it to an Ajax Request, but when I recover only one register from the Database it works, but if I have more then one, the ajax returns an error.

Below is my code:

```
public ActionResult RecuperaLocalidadesPorUsuario(int usuarioId)
{
    BpUsuario m = new BpUsuario();
    IList<Localidade> states = m.ObterPorId(usuarioId).Localidades.ToList();
    states.Add(m.ObterPorId(usuarioId).UsuaAreaPadrao);
    var result = (from s in states.Where(x => x != null).Distinct().ToList()
                  select new { id = s.LocaCodigo, name = s.LocaNome}
                 ).ToList();

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is the Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "@(Url.Action("RecuperaLocalidadesPorUsuario", "Usuario"))",
    data: { "usuarioId": selectedItem },
    contentType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("entrou no success");
        if (data.length == 0) {
            ddlLocalidades.find('option').remove();
            ddlLocalidades.append($('<option></option>').val("").html("O Usuário não tem localidades cadastradas"));
            ddlLocalidades.attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            ddlLocalidades.attr("disabled", false);
            ddlLocalidades.find('option').remove();
            ddlLocalidades.append($('<option></option>').val("").html("Todas"));
            $.each(data, function (id, option) {

                if (option.id == '@Request.Cookies.Get("UserAreaPadrao").Value') {
                    ddlLocalidades.append($('<option selected></option>').val(option.name).html(option.name));
                } else {
                    ddlLocalidades.append($('<option></option>').val(option.name).html(option.name));
                }
            });

        }

        $('#ddlLocalidades').multiselect('rebuild');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("entrou no error");
    }
});
```

I tried many links here at stackoverflow , but without any success, and I'm really stuck into this problem.

Comment: "the ajax returns an error" - what error? What steps have you taken so far to diagnose the issue?

Comment: For the first time I got to see a question where **Jon Skeet** is commenting simultaneously.. :)

Comment: from s in states.Where ... , why are you using dot between states and Where in the Linq? Please post the error message by debugging through firebug

Comment: the error is because it enters at the error clause from the ajax call .

Comment: I was looking here , and I find when the error clause is thrown , is when the second line from my controller is executed . For some reason , when I bring a list with more than one value , the error appears .

Comment: you gotta give us the exact exception message you're getting

Comment: firebug isn't returning any error message ... that's the weird thing ... the error is returning after the second line from my controller ...